# How to fix dynamic requires in third-party libraries?

Tags: node.js, webpack

My desktop app is using Electron+React for the interface and [Edge.js](https://github.com/kexplo/electron-edge) to connect Node with my C# application.

**My problem is**: Webpack is failing to bundle my application because the Edge.js dependency throws the following [error](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196):

> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

The problem is that Edge.js has the following dynamic require:

```
var compilerName = 'edge-' + language.toLowerCase();
var compiler = require(compilerName);
```

Most of the time, `compilerName` will be translated to "edge-cs", but Webpack is not able to determine this.

How can I solve this issue? People are suggesting to set the [require context](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#automatically-created-contexts-defaults-module-xxxcontextxxx) or [ContextReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/context-replacement-plugin/), but both of them are usually applied in cases where you have `require('./directory/' + variable)` and I don't know how to use them in my case where I have `require(variable)`.

**Note:** I need a solution where I don't need to modify my third-party library code.

Comment: Would using conditionals work? Eg. `if language = x then require x` rather than passing a variable name into require?

Comment: This won't work because webpack needs to bundle ALL possible requirements into the bundle and when you programmatically determine what is required, it can't tell at packing time what is needed.  But, you can use what either csilk or nilesh suggested because that shows webpack all possible things that may be needed as static strings.  It will make the code more verbose, but that's a limitation of webpack.

Comment: @jfriend00, but that would require me to change the third-party library code, right?

Comment: @user8983325 - Yes, if you want to use webpack with code that was not designed about the webpack guidelines.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but this may be relevant? https://github.com/sindresorhus/require-fool-webpack

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, Have you considered something like a massive switch below? It is suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391)

```
switch (name) {
  case 'a': return require('./a');
  case 'b': return require('./b');
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: I understand that this suggestion would fix the problem, but I would need to modify the thrid-party code, right? This switch would need to be implemented inside the node module, right?

Comment: you would write this in your code, sort of wrapper to load things you want on fly.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. The `require(variable)` is done inside the 3rd-party module module (edge.js). In my code, I'm doing `require('electron-edge')`, which is fine. The issue is inside the module. Where would I place the switch-case statement? (thx for your time)